# Parent entity without a primary key

Tags: database, database-design

As an assignment, our professor described a ERD where an entity, with a single non-key atribute acts as the parent to a weak entity.

This just does not sound right. Isn't a entity without a key considered a weak entity? If is indeed a weak entity, can it act as a parent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A week entity can very well act as a parent for another entity (weak or not).

Example: `Book`, `Edition`, `Copy`. In a library, we may have many Copies of an Edition. And we may have many Editions of a Book.

Comment: Thanks, if I have to create a relational schema for a weak parent that inherits a weak entity set, I combine the inherence rule with the rule for weak entity sets? Thanks again

Comment: What do you mean with "inherence rule"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to simple follow the single table / concrete table / class table rules.